# Problem in how to do image processing for some images - Error: AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open

Tags: python, image-processing

I get an error when performing image processing for some images using python. The error is:

> "AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'".

I would be happy if you can review the code below and help me to fix this error.

```
#imprint text on image 

from PIL import Image

from PIL import ImageFont

from PIL import ImageDraw

from IPython.display import Image

list2 = ['mydata/marketst670503.jpg','mydata/marketst8407.jpg','mydata/potsdamriot6805.jpg','mydata/rescue671221a.jpg']

outfile = 'sample-text.jpg'


for line in list2:

    print (line)

    img = Image.open(line)

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)

    font = ImageFont.truetype("Colombia.ttf", 200)

    draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,0,0),font=font)

    img.save(outfile)

    display(Image(filename=outfile))
```

Comment: You are importing two modules with the same name "from IPython.display import Image",  "from PIL import Image" which could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Notice! you have 2 imports under THE SAME NAME, overriding eachother.
I would  make this change:

```
#mabe you replace the original import to a more nutral name..
import PIL.Image as Image

from PIL import ImageFont

from PIL import ImageDraw

from IPython.display import Image as DisplayImage # this line fixes your problem

list2 = ['mydata/marketst670503.jpg','mydata/marketst8407.jpg','mydata/potsdamriot6805.jpg','mydata/rescue671221a.jpg']

outfile = 'sample-text.jpg'

for line in list2:

    print (line)

    img = Image.open(line)

    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)

    font = ImageFont.truetype("Colombia.ttf", 200)

    draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,0,0),font=font)

    img.save(outfile)

    display(Image(filename=outfile))
```

and for next time, don't confuse yourself! choose a more nutral name then Image, and there won't be duplicates :)

*** Edited!***

Comment: After I run the code, i got this error "ImportError: cannot import name "'DisplayImage'". I tried to install "DisplayImage" package, but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea in how to fix this error?

Comment: @Elwakdy I think you should rather do "from IPython.display import Image as DisplayImage" and then DisplayImage(filename...) instead of display(Image(filename...))). as I don't think module has an DisplayImage method. At least I could't find it in documentation

Comment: Hey, I made a dumb mistake, thanks! Notice the edit, I wanted you to import Image, and NAME it DisplayImage using the ‘as’ keyword. 
Now, every time you want to use the Image that comes from the Ipython.Display library, Use this name.